# Is there a way to see what stream a given CL was submitted to

Tags: python, perforce

I have a python script that grabs perforce CL information and whacks it into an xml file, but I can't seem to find a way to see what stream the changelist was submitted into. I am not sure if it is possible given that a changelist can contain files from multiple streams.

If that is the case is there an easy way to access the first file in a given CL so I can take a look at it's filepath and derive a stream from that.

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The command

```
p4 -ztag describe NNN
```

will show you each of the files in changelist NNN, as the tags

```
... depotFile0
... depotFile1
```

etc.

For example, here's a change that touched files a and b:

```
C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>p4 -ztag describe -s 13
... change 13
... user Bryan
... client Dell660
... time 1443997766
... desc both
... status submitted
... changeType public
... path //depot/*
... depotFile0 //depot/a
... action0 edit
... type0 text
... rev0 4
... fileSize0 34
... digest0 FDBA608E7A9BED6013522DBF3D3FEBAD
... depotFile1 //depot/b
... action1 edit
... type1 text
... rev1 2
... fileSize1 22
... digest1 4B44ED4AA306471B2D577EBE51D28E7E
```

So, the shortest way to get the first file in a given CL is (with a suitably modern command-line client, i.e., one which supports the -F argument):

```
p4 -F %depotFile0% -ztag describe -s NNN
```

which gives, for the above change:

```
C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>p4 -F %depotFile0% -ztag describe -s 13
//depot/a
```